# How Select Distinct Not convertable Value on a Column at SQL Sever

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, one of field is string, but the value may be int (convertable to int) and maybe string like this (Column Update By):

[image: Update By]

If the value is System Service, it means not related with User Table
If The value is convertable to int, it means related with User Table.

How can I select distinct value which not related with User Table?

*Update By is string on DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is specifically an integer you are looking for, then `not like` is better than `isnumeric()`:

```
select distinct [Update By]
from t
where [Update By] not like '%[^0-9]%';
```

Comment: How can You know that not like is better than ISNUMERIC, Sir? Is there any site or video which explain this, or You assume by testing directly and watch and compare execution time?

Comment: @toha . . . `ISNUMERIC()` doesn't guarantee conversion to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd use [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Update By] WHERE ISNUMERIC([Update By]) <> 1
```

Comment: It should be ISNUMERIC([Update By]) <> 1 as per the above question.